# How to really target table at runtime in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I have `KPI` tables and now it has more than 500M rows. I would like to split this table into `KPI_Year2011`, `KPI_Year2012`...`KPI_2020` (will be created on 1st January 2020).

PS: All tables have same structure and Entity type is `KPI`.

How would you target table at runtime like this

```
public IActionResult GetKpis(int year) {
    /*var kpis = context.KPI.where(k => k.year == year).ToList(); */
    var kpis = context.SetTargetTable($"KPI_Year{year}").ToList();
    return View(kpis);
}
```

Comment: I think it all comes down to your querying strategy. Are you going to query across the years? Do you know your typical query parameters? I'm thinking in your case it is worth implementing stored procedures that do the qurying if you have a limited set of queryies. Otherwise you can have a view that UNIONs all these table into a single table and then EF only works with that view, but I'm not sure what SQL Server will do with Performance. Also are you inserting values? or only reading?

Comment: Which RDBMS are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For you and your program, logically, it's one big table. And the fact that the database needs to split it into multiple smaller ones to make access faster should be none of your business.

This is called **Partitioning** and should really be a job of the database.

For example:

[Partitioning in SQL Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/partitions/create-partitioned-tables-and-indexes?view=sql-server-2017)

[Partitioning in Oracle](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/options/partitioning/overview/index.html)

[Partitioning in Postgres](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/ddl-partitioning.html)

[Partitioning in MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/partitioning-overview/)

You could manually implement it in your program logic, but that would just mean you reinvent the wheel. In fact, probably a much crappier and tinier wheel that breaks more often and does not really fit onto the rest of your car.

Once you leave this job to the database, your question has a solution: do nothing. Your program does not even know it's multiple tables in the database. It's one *partitioned* table.

Comment: I understand that this answer does not offer you any practical way of solving your problem, but it's quite right in that you are using the wrong approach to solve the problem. It looks like your problem is very simple and common: whatever query you are using works fine on a small dataset but not on a large one. It is better to improve the way you store records and the way you query them. 500M rows in a table are not too many, and you should be able to query such a table with no issues. Splitting your data in different tables will make it harder for programs and people to access the data.

Comment: Always happy to learn something new. Didn't know this functionality until now. It also gives the flexibility of querying the data from different tables without using "UNION" as in the case with OP's approach.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a raw query to implement this. Here is an example.

```
public IActionResult GetKpis(int year) {
    var kpis = context.KPI.FromSql($"SELECT * FROM KPI_Year{year}").ToList();
    return View(kpis);
}
```

**Update**

For inserting the data, you can use

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand($"INSERT INTO KPI_Year{year} VALUES (@col1, @col2)",
    new SqlParameter("col1", col1Value),
    new SqlParameter("col2", col2Value)
);
```

Comment: Thanks for this, in the same way, how if I want to insert data?